# How to change color of the Application Bar in Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, application-bar

In my app, I want to have the color of the application bar be white and full opaque, with no regards to the theme.  So far I have experimented with this.

```
ApplicationBar.Opacity = 1;
ApplicationBar.BackgroundColor = Color.FromArgb(52, 50, 2, 181);
```

The result was a light pink color with some transparency.  Also, I would like to keep the same theme colored (light theme) icon buttons even if the theme is dark.  I have seen apps in the WP Store (mainly Skype) that do that.  Answers gladly appreciated.

Comment: Have you had a look at [ThemeManager](https://github.com/jeffwilcox/wp-thememanager)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two ways, either in the XAML:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
    <shell:ApplicationBar BackgroundColor="White" ForegroundColor="Black">
        <shell:ApplicationBar.Buttons>
            <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton Text="A button" IconUri="/Assets/AppBar/new.png" />
        </shell:ApplicationBar.Buttons>
    </shell:ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
```

Or in the code behind:

```
using System.Windows.Media;
...
ApplicationBar.ForegroundColor = Colors.Black; // Icon and text color
ApplicationBar.BackgroundColor = Colors.White; // Application bar background color
```

Essentially the `BackgroundColor` sets the background color of the application bar and `ForegroundColor` sets the icon and text color. Setting those will keep the value regardless of theme settings.

You don't need to set the `opacity`, as the default value is 1 (full opaque).

Comment: Thank You very much, Your answer was to the point and and very easy, I appreciate that.